# Sets of morphisms that behave "like" epimorphisms/monomorphisms in a balanced category.

Tags: category-theory

> **Question.** Let $\mathbf{C}$ denote a category, and suppose $E$ and $M$ are wide subcategories such that:
>
> - $g \circ f \in E \rightarrow g \in E$
> - $g \circ f \in M \rightarrow f \in M$
> - $g \in E \cap M \leftrightarrow g \mbox{ is an isomorphism}$
>
> Does it follow that every $e \in E$ is epic and every $m \in M$ is monic?

*Motivation.* These conditions ensure that if we're given a factorization into an $E$-morphism followed by an $M$-morphism, then the $E$-morphism is the coimage and $M$-morphism is the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category generated by the diagram

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d4f474p3u3w2sh6y693sx723zi6u1x.png))</sub>

and the relation $pe=qe$. Let $M$ be the subcategory with morphisms $\{p,q,\mathrm{id}_A,\mathrm{id}_B,\mathrm{id}_C\}$ and let $E$ be the subcategory with morphisms $\{e,\mathrm{id}_A,\mathrm{id}_B,\mathrm{id}_C\}$. $E$ and $M$ satisfy the above conditions, yet $e$ is not epic. You  need to impose some saturation conditions to guarantee that morphisms in $E$ are epimorphisms.

On the other hand, as you may already know, all split epimorphisms (resp. split monomorphisms) belong to $E$ (resp. $M$).

Comment: Any idea about what those saturation conditions ought to be? Nice observation regarding sections and retractions. (I didn't know it.)